# Tagging Pandas Dataframe based on the input from the list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns (CUSTOMER NAME, PURCHASED ITEMS).. I need to create another column by tagging the seller name from whom the customer had purchased the products. How can we do this in Pandas?

Here is how the data looks like, just for illustration purpose I have added the column "SELLER NAME" manually but I wanted this column to be created automatically.

```
   CUSTOMER NAME PURCHASED ITEMS SELLER NAME
0          RAGHU          carrot    SELLER-1
1          RAGHU        broccoli    SELLER-1
2          RAGHU       asparagus    SELLER-1
3          RAGHU     cauliflower    SELLER-1
4          RAGHU            corn    SELLER-1
5          RAGHU        cucumber    SELLER-1
6          RAGHU        eggplant    SELLER-1
7          RAGHU    green pepper    SELLER-1
8          RAGHU      green peas    SELLER-1
9          RAGHU          garlic    SELLER-1
10         RAGHU    bitter guard    SELLER-1
11         RAGHU          tomato    SELLER-1
12         RAGHU          potato    SELLER-1
13         MADHU          carrot    SELLER-2
14         MADHU        broccoli    SELLER-2
15         MADHU       asparagus    SELLER-2
16         MADHU     cauliflower    SELLER-2
17         MADHU            corn    SELLER-2
18         MADHU        cucumber    SELLER-2
19         MADHU        eggplant    SELLER-2
20         MADHU    green pepper    SELLER-2
21         MADHU      green peas    SELLER-2
22         MADHU          garlic    SELLER-2
23         MADHU    bitter guard    SELLER-2
24         MADHU          tomato    SELLER-2
25         MADHU          potato    SELLER-2
26         MADHU    green chilli    SELLER-2
27         MADHU         pumpkin    SELLER-2
28          GUNA          carrot    SELLER-3
29          GUNA        broccoli    SELLER-3
30          GUNA       asparagus    SELLER-3
31          GUNA     cauliflower    SELLER-3
32          GUNA            corn    SELLER-3
33          GUNA        cucumber    SELLER-3
34          GUNA        eggplant    SELLER-3
35          GUNA    green pepper    SELLER-3
36          GUNA      green peas    SELLER-3
37          GUNA          garlic    SELLER-3
38          GUNA    bitter guard    SELLER-3
39          GUNA          tomato    SELLER-3
40         KIRAN          carrot    SELLER-4
41         KIRAN        broccoli    SELLER-4
42         KIRAN       asparagus    SELLER-4
43         KIRAN     cauliflower    SELLER-4
44         KIRAN            corn    SELLER-4
45         KIRAN        cucumber    SELLER-4
46         KIRAN        eggplant    SELLER-4
47         KIRAN    green pepper    SELLER-4
48         KIRAN      green peas    SELLER-4
49         KIRAN          garlic    SELLER-4
50         KIRAN    bitter guard    SELLER-4
51         KIRAN          tomato    SELLER-4
52         KIRAN          potato    SELLER-4
53         KIRAN           beans    SELLER-4
54         KIRAN   cluster beans    SELLER-4
55         KIRAN           onion    SELLER-4
56         KIRAN         coconut    SELLER-4
57         KIRAN           mango    SELLER-4
58         KIRAN       raw mango    SELLER-4
59         KIRAN       coriander    SELLER-4
60         KIRAN      curry leaf    SELLER-4
61         KIRAN     mint leaves    SELLER-4
62         KIRAN     corn boiled    SELLER-4
63         KIRAN         brinjal    SELLER-4
64         KIRAN      red pepper    SELLER-4
65         KIRAN   yellow pepper    SELLER-4
66         KIRAN        mushroom    SELLER-4
67         KIRAN        beetroot    SELLER-4
68         KIRAN          radish    SELLER-4
69         KIRAN           grape    SELLER-4
70         KIRAN           apple    SELLER-4
71         MUTHU          carrot     UNKNOWN
72         MUTHU        broccoli     UNKNOWN
73         MUTHU       asparagus     UNKNOWN
74         MUTHU     cauliflower     UNKNOWN
75         MUTHU            corn     UNKNOWN
76        RAKESH          carrot     UNKNOWN
77        RAKESH        broccoli     UNKNOWN
78        RAKESH       asparagus     UNKNOWN
79        RAKESH     cauliflower     UNKNOWN
80        RAKESH            corn     UNKNOWN
81        RAKESH        cucumber     UNKNOWN
82        RAKESH        eggplant     UNKNOWN
83        RAKESH    green pepper     UNKNOWN
84        RAKESH      green peas     UNKNOWN
85        RAKESH          garlic     UNKNOWN
86        RAKESH    bitter guard     UNKNOWN
87        RAKESH          tomato     UNKNOWN
88        RAKESH          potato     UNKNOWN
89        RAKESH    green chilli     UNKNOWN
```

**Seller Information:**

```
SELLER_1=["carrot", "broccoli", "asparagus", "cauliflower", "corn", "cucumber", "eggplant", "green pepper", "green peas", "garlic", "bitter guard", "tomato", "potato"]
SELLER_2=["carrot", "broccoli", "asparagus", "cauliflower", "corn", "cucumber", "eggplant", "green pepper", "green peas", "garlic", "bitter guard", "tomato", "potato", "green chilli", "pumpkin"]
SELLER_3=["carrot", "broccoli", "asparagus", "cauliflower", "corn", "cucumber", "eggplant", "green pepper", "green peas", "garlic", "bitter guard", "tomato"]
SELLER_4=["carrot", "broccoli", "asparagus", "cauliflower", "corn", "cucumber", "eggplant", "green pepper", "green peas", "garlic", "bitter guard", "tomato", "potato", "beans", "cluster beans", "onion", "coconut", "mango", "raw mango", "coriander", "curry leaf", "mint leaves", "corn boiled", "brinjal", "red pepper", "yellow pepper", "mushroom", "beetroot", "radish", "grape", "apple"]
```

**This Condition to be met:**

- Each seller sells fixed number of items. So if the customer has less number of items or more number of items that is not listed by the seller then the data should be tagged as "UNKNOWN" or else the respective seller name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's `groupby` the dataframe on `CUSTOMER NAME` and `transform` the column `PURCASED ITEMS` using a function `f` which returns the seller name corresponding to the matched items otherwise returns `UNKONOWN`:

```
def f(s):
    dct = {'SELLER_1': SELLER_1, 'SELLER_2': SELLER_2,
           'SELLER_3': SELLER_3, 'SELLER_4': SELLER_4}
    for k, v in dct.items():
        if set(v) == set(s):
            return k
    return 'UNKNOWN'


df['SELLER NAME'] = df.groupby('CUSTOMER NAME')['PURCHASED ITEMS'].transform(f)
```

---

```
   CUSTOMER NAME PURCHASED ITEMS SELLER NAME
0          RAGHU          carrot    SELLER_1
1          RAGHU        broccoli    SELLER_1
2          RAGHU       asparagus    SELLER_1
3          RAGHU     cauliflower    SELLER_1
4          RAGHU            corn    SELLER_1
5          RAGHU        cucumber    SELLER_1
6          RAGHU        eggplant    SELLER_1
7          RAGHU    green pepper    SELLER_1
8          RAGHU      green peas    SELLER_1
9          RAGHU          garlic    SELLER_1
10         RAGHU    bitter guard    SELLER_1
11         RAGHU          tomato    SELLER_1
12         RAGHU          potato    SELLER_1
13         MADHU          carrot    SELLER_2
14         MADHU        broccoli    SELLER_2
15         MADHU       asparagus    SELLER_2
16         MADHU     cauliflower    SELLER_2
17         MADHU            corn    SELLER_2
18         MADHU        cucumber    SELLER_2
19         MADHU        eggplant    SELLER_2
20         MADHU    green pepper    SELLER_2
21         MADHU      green peas    SELLER_2
22         MADHU          garlic    SELLER_2
23         MADHU    bitter guard    SELLER_2
24         MADHU          tomato    SELLER_2
25         MADHU          potato    SELLER_2
26         MADHU    green chilli    SELLER_2
27         MADHU         pumpkin    SELLER_2
28          GUNA          carrot    SELLER_3
29          GUNA        broccoli    SELLER_3
30          GUNA       asparagus    SELLER_3
31          GUNA     cauliflower    SELLER_3
32          GUNA            corn    SELLER_3
33          GUNA        cucumber    SELLER_3
34          GUNA        eggplant    SELLER_3
35          GUNA    green pepper    SELLER_3
36          GUNA      green peas    SELLER_3
37          GUNA          garlic    SELLER_3
38          GUNA    bitter guard    SELLER_3
39          GUNA          tomato    SELLER_3
40         KIRAN          carrot    SELLER_4
41         KIRAN        broccoli    SELLER_4
42         KIRAN       asparagus    SELLER_4
43         KIRAN     cauliflower    SELLER_4
44         KIRAN            corn    SELLER_4
45         KIRAN        cucumber    SELLER_4
46         KIRAN        eggplant    SELLER_4
47         KIRAN    green pepper    SELLER_4
48         KIRAN      green peas    SELLER_4
49         KIRAN          garlic    SELLER_4
...
88        RAKESH          potato     UNKNOWN
89        RAKESH    green chilli     UNKNOWN
```

Comment: Excellent, this did the trick. Can you also tell me, how you have managed to paste the dataframe here in the answer with the right alignment :) where as in the question I was not able to put them in right alignment.

Comment: Thats great! you can simply use [`to_clipboard`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_clipboard.html) method of the pandas dataframe..for example, `df.to_clipboard(sep='\s')` copies the text representation of pandas dataframe to the system clipboard which can be pasted later.